# Caption package error redux

Tags: tables, floats, errors, captions

I'm using the `caption` package, but it's not affecting the captions within my tables and figures. I've pasted my sample code below. How can it be fixed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[format=hang, justification=raggedright]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Test 1 \\ Test again}
    \caption*{\textit{Notes:} Here's a figure.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Test 2 \\ Test again}
    \caption*{\textit{Notes:} Here's a table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).  Why do you have `\caption` and `\caption*` used? Try only one for one figure or table ...

Answer (score 2):

The options are affecting the setting, although it is hard to see the raggedright since you have a forced linebreak anyway.

with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[format=hang, justification=raggedright]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Test 1 Test again 
    abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
    abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc}
    \caption*{\textit{Notes:} Here's a figure. b b b b b b b b b b b b b b }
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Test 2 \\ Test again}
  \caption*{\textit{Notes:} Here's a table. t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

If I change `hang` to `plain` it becomes

[image]